# Search bar like Finder's, with possibilities to add search parameters

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, finder, nssearchfield

I'd like to create something like this:

[image]

I can make a custom controller (maybe using a `NSCollectionView ) but it's a lot of work. Does anyone know a library or workaround in Cocoa?

Comment: obviously for add search parameters to my search logic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic Cocoa machinery for the typical app is [NSPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) (to filter your content), and an [NSPredicateEditor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSPredicateEditor_class/Reference/NSPredicateEditor.html) control.

To get fancy (have the field grow and shrink, pushing content down as rules are added), you'll need to manage / animate the views yourself as predicates are added / removed. You'll observe the view for frame changes adjust/animate the "search filter" view in your app to push down the content, etc.

Even fancier: If too many rules are added, there won't be any more room for content, so you'll need to figure out a sane limit, at which point you stop growing the view and let scrolling take over.

Comment: Perfect, i will use NSPredicateEditor